# How to default t.date to iterated date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

When the user creates a note how can we automatically set that `note.notes_date` to equal the iterated `date` shown on the notes/form?

**challenges/show**

```
<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged).each_with_index do |date, i| %>
  <div class="text-background">
    <b>Day <%= i + 1 %></b><br>
    <%= date.strftime("%m/%d") %><br><br>
    <% if @notes.present? %>
      <% @notes.each do |note| %>
        <% if note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
          <%= render "notes/notes" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render "notes/form" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render "notes/form" %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

**db**

```
create_table "notes", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "notes_text"
  t.date "notes_date" # Automatically equal this to iterated date
  t.integer  "notable_id"
  t.string   "notable_type"
  t.integer  "challenge_id"
end
```

So in other words if a user creates a note recap for **Day 2** 05/25 then the `note.notes_date == 05/25`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the date value in partial and assign that value in your form field

```
             <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing a local variable to your 'notes/form' is easy, just do:

```
<%= render partial: "notes/form", locals: {date: date} %>
```

Section 3.4.4 on [rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) covers that use case.

> #### 3.4.4 Passing Local Variables
>
> You can also pass local variables into partials, making them even more powerful and flexible. For example, you can use this technique to reduce duplication between new and edit pages, while still keeping a bit of distinct content:

Comment: Thanks Anthony :] I gave it to pitabas because his answer was a few minutes earlier than your's and his code was slightly more concise. I gave you points elsewhere though :]

Comment: I think completeness is more important when picking an answer than timelines.